# BeautifulSoup not returning html when calling Twitch

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitch

Im trying to make a web scraper for Twitch that will get the title of the stream, and the stream info. I was able to take specific parts of a page out with other websites but when I put a stream in, it doesnt look like html like in inspect element. It just looks like a big mess. So how can I extract the stream title from this?

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

request = requests.get('https://www.twitch.tv/x33n') 

#Streamer should be live

if request.status_code == 200:
  print('Webpage loaded successfully')
else:
  print('Webpage loading failed')

soup=BeautifulSoup(request.text,'html.parser')

soup = str(soup)

print(soup)

if soup != '':
  print('Parser good')
else:
  print("Parser Failed")
```

Heres the output but its much longer:

```
:flex}.shell-nav__ellipsis{width:5rem;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;display:none;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.shell__svg--navmore{fill:rgba(255,255,255,.4);height:2rem}.shell-nav__search-container{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.shell-nav__search{display:none;width:100%
```

[Jumbled mess of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQpAY.png)

Comment: It *is* returning html which also contains CSS and JS in `<style>` and `<script>` tags respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Many websites use SPA frameworks, bytecode, obscure script fragments and so on.
Therefore you have to put in extra effort
in to retrieving certain content that gets created/assembled on-the-fly/asynchronously.

How to go about what you're trying to achieve:

You could either use a headless browser api like selenium, and emulate a surfer, or you can try to emulate the calls to the internal twitch rest api.
If you're not that experienced, I suggest going the headless browser route.

Comment: Sounds complicated but I'll give it a shot

Comment: Did you check if twitch offers a public API for your purpose? because, as far as I can tell, they do. :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scrape something that is not present in the Page source using beautifulsoup. The
`the title of the stream` is loaded dynamically with Javascript. You should first check the source before scraping any page.

[view-source:https://www.twitch.tv/x33n](https://view-source:https://www.twitch.tv/x33n)

In this ^^ you won't be able to find the title of the stream. As this data is requested and loaded later.